# Python .Net Not loading .Net Standard 2.0 dll

Tags: c#, python, python.net

I am new to Python. I developed a C# library .Net Standard 2.0 and i tried to load this in Python using 
import clr 
by installing python .net package.
The problem is that if I change the version of .net to 1.4 or lower then it works otherwise it show ModuleNotFound Error.
Does anyone have idea of dealing with this problem? I don't want to change the version of my .net standard.

```
import clr
import sys
assemblydir = r"C:\\Python"
assemblypath = r"C:\\Python\Mylib.dll"
sys.path.append(assemblydir)
clr.FindAssembly(assemblypath)
clr.AddReference("Mylib")
from Mylib import Animal
a = Animal()
print (a.Get())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [changelog here](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), NetStandard 2.0 support is added on the unreleased versions.
So you are probably using PythonNet 2.3.0 or lower.
Try getting Pythonnet 2.4.0 from [appveyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/pythonnet/pythonnet/branch/master). Follow the instructions on the installation [wiki](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Installation).

Comment: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/pythonnet/pythonnet/branch/master . from this link I can't get anything

Comment: Jobs are in progress (Queued) you should wait until its finished depending on the python version you want. When its done clic on your version and go to "Artifacts".

Comment: ok...do you know .. how long will it take..I mean do I have to wait for days? :)

Comment: What version of Python do you need ?

Comment: Python version 3.6.5

Comment: I tried installing wheel file which I downloaded from artifact.. then i run pip install pythonnet it results " Requirement already satisfied: pythonnet in path (2.4.0.dev0). then i test the project with dll 2.0 but it still shows same error...Please let me know if i missed any step

Comment: Try : pip install pythonnet --upgrade

Comment: pip install pythonnet --upgrade does not install anything ...end up with the error "connection broken , timeout"

Comment: even i tried with IronPython 2.7.7 but it still did not work with .net standard 2.0

Comment: You should replace "pythonnet" with the name of your whl file: pip install yourfile.whl --upgrade if this doesn't work try uninstalling pythonnet

Comment: This still does not seem to work with Pythonnet 2.4.0 and .NET Standard 2.0 assemblies.