# call C# dll file from python

Tags: python, c#, ctypes, python.net

my C# file
Calculator.c

```
    using System;
namespace DynamicCS
   {
      public class Calculator 
      {
         public double add(double argA, double argB)
         {
             return argA + argB;
         }
         public double sub(double argA, double argB)
         {
             return argA - argB;
         }
      }
   }
```

DynamicCalc.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace DynamicCS
{
    public class DynamicCalc : DynamicObject
    {
        Calculator calc;
        public DynamicCalc()
        {
            calc = new Calculator();
        }
        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            result = null;
            switch (binder.Name)
            {
                case "add":
                    result = (Func<double, double, double>)((double a, double b)
                          => calc.add(a, b));
                    return true;
                case "sub":
                    result = (Func<double, double, double>)((double a, double b)
                          => calc.sub(a, b));
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

my python file

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\djdev\OneDrive\Desktop\hell\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0")
 
import clr
clr.AddReference(r"C:\Users\djdev\OneDrive\Desktop\hell\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\DynamicCS.dll")
 
from DynamicCS import DynamicCalc
 
calc=DynamicCalc()
 
print (calc.__class__.__name__)
# display the name of the class: 'DynamicCalc' 
 
a=7.5
b=2.5
 
res = calc.add(a, b)
print (a, '+', b, '=', res)
 
res = calc.sub(a, b)
print (a, '-', b, '=', res)
 
raw_input('Press any key to finish...')
```

my error is

```
C:\Users\djdev\OneDrive\Desktop\hell>python client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\djdev\OneDrive\Desktop\hell\client.py", line 5, in <module>
    clr.AddReference(r"C:\Users\djdev\OneDrive\Desktop\hell\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\DynamicCS.dll")
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'C:\\Users\\djdev\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\hell\\bin\\Debug\\netstandard2.0\\DynamicCS.dll' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
File name: 'C:\\Users\\djdev\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\hell\\bin\\Debug\\netstandard2.0\\DynamicCS.dll'
   at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nInit(RuntimeAssembly& assembly, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean raiseResolveEvent)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.CreateAssemblyName(String assemblyString, Boolean forIntrospection, RuntimeAssembly& assemblyFromResolveEvent)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at Python.Runtime.AssemblyManager.LoadAssembly(String name)
   at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)
```

Dll file Could not load file or assembly...... This is very important for my current project
file path is also correct....
I even tried ctypes module but error is same please tell me what should I do..

########################Thank You#############################

Comment: What version of `python` are you using? Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564191/python-net-not-loading-net-standard-2-0-dll

Comment: try to use pythonnet

Comment: I am using python 3.9 @Quercus

Comment: I already using pythonnet @rdr20